# openvpn client-connect script can't see local files?

Tags: openvpn

I run an openvpn server and I connect to it from home. My home IP is dynamic and I want to store it in a file on the server.

OS is Debian 10 and OpenVPN 2.4.7.

server.conf:

```
proto udp
port 1234
comp-lzo
keepalive 10 60
ping-timer-rem
persist-tun
persist-key
ca /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/server.crt
key /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/server.key
dh /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/dh2048.pem
reneg-sec 0
cipher AES-256-CBC
server 192.168.123.0 255.255.255.0
route 192.168.9.0 255.255.255.0
client-to-client
client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/clients
status /etc/openvpn/status
verb 3
log /var/log/openvpn.log
script-security 3
client-connect /etc/openvpn/openvpn-client-connect.sh
```

/etc/openvpn/openvpn-client-connect.sh:

```
awk -F ',' '/192.168.123.5/ { print $3 }' /etc/openvpn/status | awk -F ':' '{ print $1 }' > /home/s/home-ip
chown s:s /home/s/home-ip
```

But it doesn't work and openvpn.log says:

> /etc/openvpn/openvpn-client-connect.sh: line 3: /home/s/home-ip: No such file or directory

Of course /home/s/home-ip do exist and when I execute /etc/openvpn/openvpn-client-connect.sh from shell, it all works. What's wrong here?

Comment: Check permissions, is /home/s readable by the openvpn service user?

Comment: Are you starting openvpn with systemd? If yes, then I might have a workaround for you

Comment: @Alex Yes, it starts with systemd (the default Debian setup)
NiKiZe openvpn runs as root, there's no additional user

Comment: Please try writing the contents with tee instead of >

Comment: @Alex the script isn't run by systemd but openvpn though

Comment: However, perhaps you do need a shebang or something, or your script is broken in some way (bad quoting, etc.). The error doesn't look like one that cause by `chown`ing a non-existing file, but instead attempting to execute a non-existing file

Comment: I was going to propose writing an ExecPost with the systemd service but that would launch the script once, not per connection and he'd have to make some checks periodically with the script so it becomes pointless to have it in ExecPost. Thats why I asked but I changed my mind eventually. OP, write the contents to your file with tee not with > and see if openvpn likes it